# sqlalchemy check how many changes the session includes

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I'm trying to print to my log how many objects were inserted/updated/deleted during the transaction. 
I saw in the docs the following properties :

session.dirty - The set of all persistent instances considered dirty.
session.new - The set of all instances marked as ‘new’ within this Session.
session.deleted - The set of all instances marked as ‘deleted’ within this Session

I'm using the following logging command but the values assigned to the length of the sets is 0 although I commit new /dirty objects :

```
logger.info(
                "commiting , new objects  : {} , updated objects : {}, deleted objects : {}".format(
                    len(session.new), len(session.dirty), len(session.deleted))
            )
session.commit()
```

output :

```
commiting , new object  : 0 , updated objects : 0, deleted objects : 0
```

The way I insert my data is in bulks, with the func bulk_save_objects(), and the way I update it is with a query that uses the synchronize_session=False flag. Any change that this is the reason ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've hit the nail on the head. `Session.bulk_save_objects()` and `synchronize_session=False` both skip the session machinery. On the other hand you'd not get the counts for objects not loaded to the session before a bulk `Query.update()`, even if using synchronization.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. If they skip the session obj, when are they commited ? (session.commit() ? )

Comment: The changes sent to the database are a part of the same running database transaction, so you're right again; they're committed with `Session.commit()`.

Comment: Got it , thanks ! Are u familiar with any other way to keep track of the session objects that are commited ?

Comment: In case of bulk operations `Query.update()` and `Query.delete()` they return the number of rows that matched, which on the other hand may not be the number of affected rows, at least for update. You could keep a tally based on those.

Comment: understood tnx !